# Why can I update my table connect by foreign key?

Tags: php, laravel

I have got a problem with an update function in Laravel. It works correctly for my main table with a primary key.
I can not update my table which is connected with my main table by foreign key. When I try to update my table I'm receiving:

> Call to a member function update() on null

```
Function Update Code:
public function update(Request $request, $id_faktura){
  $update_invoice = Faktura::findOrFail($id_faktura);
  $update_sprzedawca = Faktura::where($id_faktura = 'id')->with('sprzedawca')->first();
  $update_nabywca = Faktura::where($id_faktura = 'id')->with('nabywca')->first();
  $update_invoice->update($request->all());
  $update_sprzedawca ->update($request->all());
  $update_nabywca ->update($request->all());
  $update_sprzedawca->push();
  $update_nabywca->push();
  $update_invoice->nabywca()->associate($update_nabywca);
  $update_invoice->sprzedawca()->associate($update_sprzedawca);
  $update_invoice->push(); 
      return redirect('showinvoice');           
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What do you think `Faktura::where($id_faktura = 'id')` is doing?

Comment: I think this help me find a id from table faktura witch add update 
correctly table witch is connect by foreign key.

Comment: You're just assigning the string "id" to `$id_faktura` and then searching for that. Even if you were passing the original `$id_faktura` you'd just end up with three copies of the same object.

Comment: okk Do you know how can i write good code to update function?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your goal is, and this is not a tutorial site. I suggest some other sites to learn the basics of Laravel and Eloquent relations, and then come back here with a specific problem.

Comment: my specific problem is i can nto update a table that is connect by foreign key with my main table

Comment: Are the following lines of code returning anything at all?
$update_sprzedawca = Faktura::where($id_faktura = 'id')->with('sprzedawca')->first();
  $update_nabywca = Faktura::where($id_faktura = 'id')->with('nabywca')->first();

If not, do as comments say above, and learn the basics about query building. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses
**Model::find and Model::where are different.

Comment: also if you are working with Foreign keys, I'd recommend brushing up on relationships as you've written some redundant code if the intent is to get a model by ID then access models linked via foreign key/relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You should fix all your where queries. 
Solution:

`Faktura::where($id_faktura, 'id')->with('nabywca')->first();`